# Yii - update record with filefield

Tags: file-upload, yii

I am developing a database interface using Yii. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/2/) in order to enable file upload when creating a new record, but I have a problem with the update. I want the user to be able to fill the other form fields, without the need to upload the file again. I tried this in the `_form` view

```
<?php if($model->isNewRecord){ ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'filename'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'filename'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'filename'); ?>
    </div>
    <?php }else{ ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'filename', array('value'=>$model->filename)); ?>        
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

But when I submit the form I get the error **Filename cannot be blank**. Note that in my model I declared the following rule:

```
array('filename', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png),
```

Is there a standard way to implement record udate in the presence of a file field? How can I change my code?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify in the rules that the file need not be submitted.

```
array('filename', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true),
```

The allowEmpty will remove the place a non-mandatory condition for the file upload field.

If you want the file to to mandatory on create, but not on update, you can use this.

```
array('filename', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>false, 'on'=>'create'),
array('filename', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, jpeg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true, 'on'=>'update'),
```

References : http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/4727-uploaded-file-allowempty-rule-only-in-a-certain-scenario/